# Scroll is enabled only after refreshing the page ng-view angular

Tags: angularjs, autoscroll, ng-view

Need help in resolving the scroll issue.

I have enabled the overflow attribute for the ng-view div, the view which loads has no scroll enabled. The scroll becomes visible only after the browser is reloaded or refreshed.

Note: css for ng-view are inline.

Comment: To understand the issue better, can you please provide a demo example using something like jsfiddle?

Comment: @NitinGarg Thanks for the comment!! After doing some more research was able to implement the scroll bar using ng-scrollable module form https://github.com/echa/ng-scrollable. Don't know what was the issue with the regular overflow scroll attribute css. Anyways now it is working. And have answered it as well

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research was able to implement the scroll bar using ng-scrollable module form https://github.com/echa/ng-scrollable. Don't know what was the issue with the regular overflow scroll attribute css. Anyways now it is working

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you're doing wrong since I cannot see any of your code here so I'm directing you to a guess based solution. You should try enabling `autoscroll=true` in your `ng-view` directive.

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView),

> autoscroll -
>
> - If the attribute is not set, disable scrolling.
> - If the attribute is set without value, enable scrolling.